# React Native Config.h not found

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native

I'm beginner of React native developer.

After create new project then open it.

xcode is display error **config.h** file not found in **mutex.h** file. I'm also search in google and try possible solution but still display same error.

I'm done Following Commands

**1**

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**2**

```
brew install watchman
```

**3**

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

**4**

```
react-native init projectName
```

**5**

```
cd projectName
react-native start
```

**6**

```
react-native run-ios
```

> **Error in CMD**
> ./Desktop/Demo React Native/projectName/node_modules/react-native/React/../third-party/glog-0.3.4/src/base/mutex.h:105:10: fatal error: 'config.h' file not found
>
> ## include "config.h"           // to figure out pthreads support
>
> 1 error generated.

**Software Version List**
Homebrew 1.6.8
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.55
watchman 4.9.0
npm 6.1.0

**I'm also try this soluation but still error**

In the Terminal, navigate to the **third-party/glog** and **config glog** file

```
cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4
./../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**I got it fixed by following this steps:**

1. Close **Xcode**.
2. `cd <Project-Folder>/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4`
3. Run `./configure`
4. Run `make`
5. Run `make install`
6. Open **Xcode** and try building the Project.

Hope this solves the issue

Comment: I'm remove "node_modules" then run "yarn install" command then after your ans 2nd and 3rd step run it properly working with react-native 0.56 version

Comment: @BhaumikSurani thanks for the insights... in some scenarios 4th  -  5th step is need ....didnt get time to actually see why its needed in some situtaions ..but the above step is kind of solution to get it working

Comment: I'm new to iOS, what is `make`?

Comment: `make` is a build tool, usually used with C/C++ projects.  http://www.gnu.org/software/make/ What it does is configured by the `Makefile` in the directory. Steps 3-5 are the steps for building and installing https://github.com/google/glog

Comment: in my case third-party folder is missing, please help.

Answer (score 7):

**2023 solution Update**

It seems like it changed to:
#import "RNCConfig.h"

just remove 'ReactNativeConfig.h' and replace it with 'RNCConfig.h'

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. Also there is an instance that'll look similar to `NSDictionary* env = [ReactNativeConfig env];`
That will need to be changed to `... [RNCConfig env];`

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
yarn upgrade log
```

Upgrade to v1.6.0 successful. iOS build successful.

Note: Rebuilding glog did did not work for me. Build failed.

Answer (score 2):

I will add another answer to this issue since it was driving me crazy this week...

```
$ cd ./node_modules/react-native && scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh && cd third-party && cd $(ls | grep 'glog' | awk '{print $1}') && ./configure
```

The steps needed to manually configure glog (like samridhgupta his accepted answer or the command I wrote here just above) worked for me, but only the first time I build the project. On every single build I had to go to the same process so I needed a more stable solution.

I appears Xcode is executing **ios-install-third-party.sh** on every build, which means it will also execute **ios-configure-glog.sh** every single time. So my solution is to just build a single time, and then comment out the glog install step in the ios-install-third-party script.

If anyone is facing this same issue, it is the line below you need to remove or comment out (ios-install-third-party can be found in /node_modules/react-native/scripts).

```
fetch_and_unpack glog-0.3.5.tar.gz https://github.com/google/glog/archive/v0.3.5.tar.gz 61067502c5f9769d111ea1ee3f74e6ddf0a5f9cc "\"$SCRIPTDIR/ios-configure-glog.sh\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Run following commands in project directory.Helped me resolve my config.h not found issue

1. cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/
2. ./configure
3. make
4. make install
5. cd ../../../..
6. react-native run-ios

Comment: after make Command display following
**make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.**

Comment: issue is solved **react-native init with lower version**

Answer (score 1):

**What worked for me:**

```
yarn cache clean
rm -rf node_modules
yarn install
```

Answer (score 1):

**If any of these solution does not work, please check your project path. Project path - directory names should not contain any space in its name or you can create project on Desktop or in Documents directory.**

Answer (score 1):

Add this `fix` script into `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "fix": "cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4 && ./configure && make && make install"
  },
```

Then run `yarn fix` or `npm run fix` and then try building the Project

Answer (score 0):

My problem was comming from using react-native@0.53.0, which I suppose has trouble with new Xcode version.

**1 - Change react-native version in `package.json`**

```
"react-native": "0.53.0",
```

to

```
"react-native": "0.56.0",
```

**2 - Remove `node_modules` folder**

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/
```

**3 - Reinstall modules:**

```
$ yarn install
```